# igraph in R: Making image() plot an adjacency matrix with the axis starting in the top-left instead of the bottom-left corner?

Tags: r, igraph

I am using `igraph` in `R` to use a Stochastic Block Model for the basis of generating an adjacency matrix. In the matrix itself, the rows start down the top left corner downwards, while columns start in the top left corner to the right. When I plot it in `R` using `image()`, the orientation doesn't match what a regular matrix would be. It instead has the axis start in the bottom left corner.

```
library(igraph)
pm <- matrix(rep(0.9, 100*100), ncol = 100)
diag(pm) <- rep(0.01, 100)
g <- sample_sbm(1000, pref.matrix = pm, block.sizes = rep(1000/100,100))
A <- as.matrix(as_adj(g))
image(A, useRaster = T)
```

[image]

Is there a way to simply make it so that `image()` starts from the top left corner instead?

Comment: reverse the y-axis? `image(A, ylim=c(1,0), useRaster = TRUE)`

Comment: Sorry, I meant if there was a way to plot the red diagonal line above as coming from the top left to the bottom right -- similar to a transpose? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flip the image without flipping the axes by reversing the order of either the rows or the columns

```
image(A[,ncol(A):1], useRaster = TRUE)
image(A[nrow(A):1,], useRaster = TRUE)
```

[image: Flipped matrix]